# developing a cms with spring

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, content-management-system

I am trying to develop a cms with spring but I am confused how to create my controllers for frontend app.

I have categories and articles each with name, details, pictures, dates, author etc. A category can have more categories or articles. Each category and article will have a parent and unique link.

How should I `map` my `Controller` ? I can't create `a new controller` or a new `@RequestMapping` every time I create a new category or article.

So what is the idea of the controller so I can navigate on my app through categories and articles ?

Comment: what do you mean by `cms`

Comment: Use `@PathVariable`s and a generic URL base.

Comment: content management system, so I can create my categories, articles from a backend to my site

Comment: Again, I would suggest looking into using `@PathVariable`s, which can use regular expressions.

Comment: ok, thanks. From what I've seen so far it might do the trick.